# Convert delimited string to rows

Tags: string

I have data in this format `9561|9560|9564|9563|9559`

I need data in this format

```
9561 
9560 
9564 
9563 
9559
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which programming language or tools are you using?

Comment: Why is this tagged `qa` "Quality Assurance"?

Answer (score -1):

String str="9561|9560|9564|9563|9559";
String splits[]=str.split("\|");
for(Sring s : splits)
System.out.println(s);

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a text editor such as Sublime on a Mac, you can try:

1. Cmd + Shift + F
2. Click the regex button (".*")
3. Find: \|
4. Where:  select
5. Replace: \n
6. click replace